# How to give Write Permission In IIS Version5.1?

Tags: asp.net, iis, deployment

I have developed an web application using Asp.net ( .Net Framework 3.0). In this application I have created a folder in the application directory. This folder contains an xml file to read and write data. when I tested this application in my local machine I can read and write data. But, when I deployed in IIS Ver5.1, I can read the data but when I try to write data in xMl file i could not.

So, I hope this problem is in IIS. I gave the write permission to my application folder in IIS.

or Is there any steps to do that?

How to give write text file persmission in IIS Ver5.1?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Setting IIS Web Site Permissions](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/cf7f59d4-9ab9-4038-a482-d72d3e6f801e.mspx?mfr=true).

From Microsoft TechNet.

Answer (score 0):

After deployed my web application in IIS. When I try to write file in xml file. I could not wirte. It redirected to another page. So, the file is not written. But, it is writing in local machine...

thanks